# How can I use the index of a pandas series or dataframe as index of an indexed variable in sympy?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, sympy, symbolic-math

I would like to combine the symbolic math of sympy (e.g. solving and differentiation of indexed symbolic variables) with pandas series or dataframes (indexed exogenous data).
In my application, there would just be one index for both, sympy and pandas.

#### Example:

This example should solve for the indexed symbolic variable `re[i]` for each `i`, given the data from two series `qt` and `pr` that also use index `i`.

I defined the index, i, and the indexed symbol, re:

```
re = IndexedBase("re")
i = symbols("i", cls=Idx)
i = ["X", "Y", "Z"]
```

Then, I created the series with the same index
(It could be a dataframe, too. Also, data need not be limited to integers.):

```
pr = pd.Series([4, 5, 6], i, name="pr")
qt = pd.Series([2, 2, 2], i, name="qt")
```

The series look as follows:
pr

```
X  4
Y  5
Z  6
```

qt

```
X  2
Y  2
Z  2
```

Next, I tried to use sympy's solveset to solve for `re[i]`:

```
solveset(qt * pr - re[i], re[i])
```

My **expected result** was something like:

```
re[X] = 8
re[Y] = 10
re[Z] = 12
```

But the actual output was:

```
ValueError: 0     -re[X, Y, Z] + 8
1    -re[X, Y, Z] + 10
2    -re[X, Y, Z] + 12
dtype: object is not a valid SymPy expression
```